# Swift: Why all my optional variable looks like "Optional(305.502)"

Tags: ios, swift, optional-variables

I've just start learning swift. And I am a little be confused with optional types. I have some variable `var theOptVar: Float?` it can be nil so I make it optional with `?`.
But when I'd like to get it somewhere at UI I see `Optional(305.502)`.
Is there way to have optional var on `UILabel` without "Optional" word?

Comment: about which you are sure that there will be value so remove optional sign "?"

Comment: You can use ther implicitly unwrapped syntax of `Float!` rather than `Float?`. It's still an optional, but will be implicitly unwrapped every time you use it (so make sure it's not `nil` before you try to use it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is displaying “Optional” because you have changed its datatype from `Float` to `Optional Float`.
Due to this whatever value is there will be automatically wrapped into **Optional** text.

So if you don’t want to display optional word just extract the value out of it.

To do so add **`!`** mark . **This is forced unwrapping.**

For eg.

```
var temp : Float?
temp = 60.5
println(Value \(temp!))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the implicit unwrapping that Rob describes (`aFloat!`, which will crash if aFloat is nil)

or

Optional Binding

```
if let requiredFloat = aFloat
{
  //Code that only runs if aFloat is != nil
  println("aFloat = \(requiredFloat)")
}
else
{
  println("aFloat = nil")
}
```

Optional binding does two things for you: It checks to see if the optional is nil, and skips the block of code if it is nil. If it is NOT nil, it assigns the optional to a required constant which you can use inside your if code.